# Error in plpgsql parameters in WHERE clause

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I created a function used for filtering

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION filtersearch(
    val1 text[] DEFAULT NULL::text[],
    val2 text[] DEFAULT NULL::text[],
    val3 text[] DEFAULT NULL::text[],
    val4 boolean DEFAULT NULL::boolean)
    RETURNS SETOF student_table
    LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'

AS $BODY$

DECLARE
   where_val text := '';
   result_text int;
BEGIN

    IF $4 = true THEN
        where_val := 'attendance = true';
        raise notice 'Value: %', where_val;
    END IF;
    
    
RETURN QUERY EXECUTE    
'SELECT * FROM student_table"
    WHERE (LOWER("student_name") = ($1) OR $1 IS NULL)
    AND ((LOWER("subject") = ($2)) OR $2 IS NULL)
    AND ((LOWER("comments") ILIKE $3) 
        OR ($3 IS NULL) 
        )
    '|| where_val ||'' USING where_val;
    --raise notice 'Value: %', result_text;
END 
$BODY$;
```

I am having an error in calling it,

> ERROR:  op ANY/ALL (array) requires array on right side

Any suggestions or comments in my code is deeply appreciated

Here's the sample data for my table

| student_name | subject | professor | comments | attendance |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Amelia | Math | Digory Kirkle |  | TRUE |
| Benjamin | Science | Hari Seldon |  | FALSE |
| Charlotte | English | Lee Everett |  | TRUE |
| Amelia | English | Lee Everett |  | FALSE |

I am calling the code like this

```
SELECT filtersearch(
    (array['Amelia, Charlotte']::text[]), 
    (NULL), 
    (NULL), 
    (true)
)
```

Comment: Can you create an MVE with sample data? We can't call a function without you creating us a `student_table`. How are you calling this code?

Comment: I added a sample data in my question thank you very much

Comment: To compare arrays, you need to use `= any ($1)` But you are not passing 3 arguments to `execute query` - only **one**  which is either `''` or `'attendance = true'`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name i encountered an error ERROR:  op ANY/ALL (array) requires array on right side how do I fix it?

Comment: As I said: you need to pass **3** parameters (the arguments of the function), not just one with the `using` clause.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name thank you very much! i called $1 together with the where_val

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The $1, $2, $3 placeholders inside the SQL *string* reference the parameters passed through the `USING` clause of the `EXECUTE QUERY` command. You are only passing one argument which is either `''` or the string `'attendance = true'` - neither can be used for an `IN` condition.

So you need to pass the three parameters with the USING clause, but **not** the string that you append to the SQL query. If you are using ILIKE there is no need to use `lower()` with that condition. Your `where_val` string also missing an `AND` (or an `OR`)

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION filtersearch(
    val1 text[] DEFAULT NULL::text[],
    val2 text[] DEFAULT NULL::text[],
    val3 text[] DEFAULT NULL::text[],
    val4 boolean DEFAULT NULL::boolean)
    RETURNS SETOF student_table
    LANGUAGE plpgsql

AS $BODY$

DECLARE
   where_val text := '';
BEGIN

  IF $4 = true THEN
    where_val := 'AND attendance = true';
    raise notice 'Value: %', where_val;
  END IF;
    
  RETURN QUERY EXECUTE    
   'SELECT * 
    FROM student_table
      WHERE (LOWER(student_name) = ANY($1) OR $1 IS NULL)
      AND (LOWER(subject") = ANY ($2) OR $2 IS NULL)
      AND (LOWER("comments") ILIKE ANY($3) OR $3 IS NULL)
     '|| where_val
  USING val1, val2, val3; -- do NOT pass where_val here
END 
$BODY$;
```

You don't really need dynamic SQL for this. You can apply the same logic as you tried with the first 3 parameters for the boolean parameter.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION filtersearch(
    val1 text[] DEFAULT NULL::text[],
    val2 text[] DEFAULT NULL::text[],
    val3 text[] DEFAULT NULL::text[],
    val4 boolean DEFAULT NULL::boolean)
    RETURNS SETOF student_table
    LANGUAGE plpgsql

AS $BODY$
BEGIN

  RETURN QUERY
    SELECT * 
    FROM student_table
      WHERE (LOWER(student_name) = any(val1) OR val1 IS NULL)
        AND (LOWER(subject) = any(val2) OR val2 IS NULL)
        AND (comments ILIKE ANY(val3) OR val3 IS NULL)
        AND (attendance = val4 or val4 = false or val4 is null);
END 
$BODY$;
```

You wouldn't even need PL/pgSQL for the above.